# Android Marshmallow permission is not granted, when Notification present on the screen

Tags: android, permissions, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have a trouble with Marshmallow permissions usage together with Notification.

Every time when I receive SMS notification (*or similar*)

[image]

And if Request Permission Dialog present on the same time on the screen(when notification is appears), I have a misbehavior : I tap on `Allow` button, Permission Dialog is dismissed and all looks good **for the first look**. 
**But**, when I try to use the same permission, I suppose I have a granted permission, **but is not**. System tell me that permission is not granted. Permission Request Dialog appears again. And when I tap `Allow` again, but without notification overlapping system takes me permission successfully.

How I can come over this situation?

---

How I check permission?

I extend all my activities from MarshmallowSupportActivity :

```
public abstract class MarshmallowSupportActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


    public void requestPermission(String permission, int requestCode) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{permission}, requestCode);
        } else {
            onPermissionGranted(permission, requestCode);
        }
    }

    public void requestPermission(int requestCode, String... permissions) {
        int notGrantedPermissionsCount = 0;
        for (String permission : permissions) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                notGrantedPermissionsCount++;
            } else {
                onPermissionGranted(permission, requestCode);
            }
        }

        String[] requestedPermissions = new String[notGrantedPermissionsCount];
        int counter = 0;

        for (String permission : permissions) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                requestedPermissions[counter] = permission;
                counter++;
            }
        }

        if (notGrantedPermissionsCount != 0) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, requestedPermissions, requestCode);
        }
    }

    public void requestPermission(String permission) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{permission}, 255);
        } else {
            onPermissionGranted(permission, 255);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String permissions[], @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < permissions.length && j < grantResults.length; i++, j++) {
            if (grantResults[j] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                onPermissionGranted(permissions[i], requestCode);
            } else {
                onPermissionDenied(permissions[i], requestCode);
            }
        }
    }

    public void onPermissionGranted(String permission, int requestCode) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void onPermissionDenied(String permission, int requestCode) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

and use :

```
requestPermission(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
```

with @Overriding `onPermissionGranted` and `onPermissionDenied` on requested activity.

Comment: what is your code in `onPermissionGranted()` ?

Comment: @user2450263 I include.